# Counting data with week interval and parameter date in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting-services

I'm trying to count data with interval week from parameter start date to end date. so far i got this code:

```
SELECT  TRUNC(HAZARD_DATE, 'WW') week, count(*) as TOTAL 
FROM T_HAZARD a
WHERE A.HAZARD_DATE BETWEEN :parStart AND :parEnd
GROUP BY TRUNC(HAZARD_DATE, 'WW')
ORDER BY WEEK ASC
```

And the result:

```
    WEEK    TOTAL
1/1/2018    181
1/8/2018    289
1/15/2018   344
1/22/2018   288
```

the result i want:

```
WEEK    TOTAL
 1      181
 2      289
 3      344
 4      288
```

Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. You just need to replace the `TRUNC` function by a `TO_CHAR` (with the same format `WW`). This will return the week number, while `TRUNC(..., 'WW')` returns the date of the first day of the week.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(HAZARD_DATE, 'WW') week, count(*) as TOTAL 
FROM T_HAZARD a
WHERE A.HAZARD_DATE BETWEEN :parStart AND :parEnd
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(HAZARD_DATE, 'WW')
ORDER BY WEEK ASC
```

Comment: Welcome @fadiladam !

Comment: If the hazard_date is across months and years (2/5/2018,2/12/2018 etc) is the answer as expected?

Comment: Note, `WW` means: "Week of year (1-53) where week 1 starts on the first day of the year and continues to the seventh day of the year." So, the week may start on any day from Monday to Sunday. Is that what you like to get?